# Flexbox: last nav list item moving to a new line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation, flexbox

I am trying to create a navbar that on the same line. I've tried using flex-direction: row. to make all the list items inline but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```css
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .main-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .logo-name {
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    padding: 0.3em;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <h1 class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></h1>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FREE QUOTE</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: The menu items are on the same line when the screen width is greater than 900px, which is what you have set in your media query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies at `@media (min-width: 900px)`, just move your css code outside `@media (min-width: 900px)` block then everything will work. A minor problem is you have defined `li` tag inside `nav` tag which is semantically incorrect, invalid markup, you should replace `nav` with `ul` tag

```css
@media (min-width: 100px) {
  
}
.main-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .logo-name {
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    padding: 0.3em;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <h1 class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></h1>

  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FREE QUOTE</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-wrap: no-wrap;` if the menu should not come in 2 lines.

```css
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-name {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.main-nav {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0.3em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <h1 class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">R.J Roofer</a></h1>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <li class="nav-item-1"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FREE QUOTE</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
```